# How can I use AJAX to skip part of the php when I press a submit input button?

Tags: php, html

Below I have a short program. When the page initially loads, it shows an alert. When the button is pressed, because it is of type submit, the whole php reloads and shows an alert again before changing the button's color to green. I would like to not show the alert upon reload, only change the button's color to green. Is there a way I can use AJAX to not skip the first line in the php and go directly to the second line when I press the submit button? Much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">     
        <style type="text/css">
            .sub
            {
                background-color: #1f5a7c;
                border: none;
                font-weight: bold;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <form method="POST" >       
            <input type="submit" name="TestButton" id="TestButton" value="Test Button" class="sub">
        </form>                                                 
    </body>
</html>

<?php   
    if(isset($_POST["TestButton"]))         
    {                                   
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>TestButton.style.background='green';</script>";    
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Start')</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake, the code is below

Comment: The alert is always going to show if $_POST["TestButton"] is not set. This is set before the browser receives the web page. Ajax would not help in this situation. What is it your tying to learn?

Comment: first off,   document.getElementById('TestButton').style.background='green'; I would also do a check if the document loaded and put the PHP at the top.

Comment: you are essentially echoing Document.getElementById('TestButton').style.background='green'; } else {<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Start')</script> } ?>  the only part running is the alert!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SESSION`s to do this:

```
<?php   
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST["TestButton"]))         
    {                                   
         $_SESSION['submitted'] = true; 
    }

    if ($_SESSION['submitted'] === true){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>TestButton.style.background='green';</script>"; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Start')</script>";
    }
?>
```

Conversely .. In your program .. Wherever you need to "restart" the user "from the beginning"  simply destroy the session:

```
<?php
     session_destroy(); 
<?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_POST["TestButton"]))         
    {  ?>                                 
       <script type='text/javascript'>Document.getElementById('TestButton').style.background='green'; </script>    
       <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
       <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Start')</script>
   <?php
    }

?>
```

Try this.

Sometimes the echo does not work as intended so you are free to add the script by wrapping the logic part of the php in php tags. What is likely happening is everything from the first  '>'  is executing as if you put php tags because of the close carrot. so the alert is always triggered.